# Problems with my for loops printing out my arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops

can anybody help me figure out why my for loops cant print the right answer out.
Its like its skipping the first array number [0]. but if i try to make it print out my Array nr [1] out it works fine. 
It must be somthing with my counter ans `answer` at the top.

```
package assignment9.pkg1;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Anders
 */
public class Assignment91 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String studName = "Anders";
        int counter = 1;// i think the problem is here
        int answer = 1; // same
        System.out.println(" welcome to student database, show informations about student" + studName);

        Scanner courseScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner gradeScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner answerScan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(" Enter the name of courses");

        String[] courseArray = new String[counter];
        int[] gradeArray = new int[counter];

        for (int k = 0; k <= counter; k++) {

            if (counter < 20) {

                while (answer != 0) {  // what have i done here with that 0 answer??

                    System.out.println(" enter name");
                    courseArray[k] = courseScan.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(" Enter grade");
                    gradeArray[k] = gradeScan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(" Do you want to add one more course enter 1, if not enter 0");
                    answer = answerScan.nextInt();

                }
            } else {

                System.out.println("Sorry, there is no more memory");

            }
        }

        int n = gradeArray.length;
        int temp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {

                if (gradeArray[j - 1] > gradeArray[j]) {
                    //swap the elements!
                    temp = gradeArray[j - 1];
                    gradeArray[j - 1] = gradeArray[j];
                    gradeArray[j] = temp;

                    // Swap the course array
                    String gradeArrayTemp;

                    gradeArrayTemp = courseArray[j - 1];
                    courseArray[j - 1] = courseArray[j];
                    courseArray[j] = gradeArrayTemp;

                }

            }

        }

        for (int l = 0; l < courseArray.length; l++) {

            System.out.println("grade " + gradeArray[l] + "name " + courseArray[l]); // why does it not print all the array out
        }

        Scanner request = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(" what do you want to do. Enter 1 to rename a course");
        System.out.println(" enter 2 to change a grade ");
        int regNumber = request.nextInt();
        switch (regNumber) {

            case 1: // rename a course

                Scanner search = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter the name of the course you want to rename");
                String searchCourse = search.nextLine();

                for (int i = 0; i < courseArray.length; i++) {
                    if (searchCourse.equals(courseArray[i])) {

                        System.out.println("Yes there is a course named " + courseArray[i]);
                        System.out.println(" to change coursename insert new name");
                        // here i change the coursename
                        Scanner newName = new Scanner(System.in);
                        courseArray[i] = newName.nextLine();

                    } else {

                        System.out.println(" no record of this course");

                    }

                    System.out.println(" you have chosen to rename course into " + courseArray[i]);

                }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output??

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this section of the code:

```
 for (int k = 0; k <= counter; k++) {

            if (counter < 20) {

                while (answer != 0) {  // what have i done here with that 0 answer??

                    System.out.println(" enter name");
                    courseArray[k] = courseScan.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(" Enter grade");
                    gradeArray[k] = gradeScan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(" Do you want to add one more course enter 1, if not enter 0");
                    answer = answerScan.nextInt();

                }
            } else {

                System.out.println("Sorry, there is no more memory");

            }
        }
```

note that you have used `k` to insert into array. the `k` do not update because is stuck in the inner `while loop` There for use another counter.

Also here

`String[] courseArray = new String[counter];`

you use counter to create the array. Which is 1. You are creating one eliment array.

You code will work like this:

```
 int k = 0;

            if (counter < 20) {

                while (answer != 0) {  // what have i done here with that 0 answer??

                    System.out.println(" enter name");
                    courseArray[k] = courseScan.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(" Enter grade");
                    gradeArray[k] = gradeScan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(" Do you want to add one more course enter 1, if not enter 0");
                    answer = answerScan.nextInt();
                    k++;
                }
            } else {

                System.out.println("Sorry, there is no more memory");

            }
```

And

```
for (int i = 0; i < courseArray.length; i++) {
            if(courseArray[i] != null)
            System.out.println("grade " + gradeArray[i] + "name " + courseArray[i]); // why does it not print all the array out
        }
```

I have assumed that you take only 20 records depending on the loop. So i initiated arrays

```
 String[] courseArray = new String[20];
        int[] gradeArray = new int[20];
```

Comment: Note that there are many efficient ways to do this. Please Google them.